# Explicit formula for zeta function with special type of weight

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

Consider the following line of thinking:

$$\pi(x) = \operatorname{R}(x) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho}) - \frac1{\ln x} + \frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x} $$

Here,
$\operatorname{R}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \mu (n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n})$

Now by Stieltjes Integral:

$\int_a^bf(x)d(π(x))=\sum_{a\leq{p}\leq{b}}f(p)$

i.e. the integral counts $f$-weighted primes

For our simplicity let's consider $f$ to be analytic for our domain

Now consider the following function :

$$f(x) = \sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x}\right)\\\\$$

For every integer other than prime $f(x)$ is zero

Now as we can see for each prime $p\geq5$

$$\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(p)}{2p}\right)\ = \cos^2\left(\frac{π}{2p}\right)\\\\$$

Define: $\cos^2\left(\frac{π}{2x}\right)= F(x)$

Now consider the following two equations:

> Eq1:
> $\int_5^bF(x)d(π(x))=\sum_{5\leq{p}\leq{b}}F(p)==\sum_{5\leq{p}\leq{b}}f(p)$

(π(x) is as mentioned above)

> Eq2: Finite version of Abel- Plana Summation on f(x):

> $$\begin{align}f(x) = {} & \sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x}\right)\\
> \sum_{k=5}^b f(k)= {} & \frac{f(5) +f(b)}2 + \int_5^b f(x) \, dx \\ & {}+ i\int_0^∞\frac{f(5+iy) − f(5−iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy +i \int_0^∞\frac{f(b-iy) − f(b+iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy
> \end{align}$$

As we can see for every integer $b$ ( only integer)

> Eq(1)=Eq(2)

Here , what we have done is creating a duality with two (seemingly) different pieces of information ( prime sieving by zeta zeros and prime sieving by gamma function) using two different methods or tools ( Stieltjes Integral  and Abel Plana ) So here I'm curious if something comes out of it .

Also we can further modify the weight at our service but I'm not gonna go into that because it's irrelevant for my instant aim .

Questions:

> Is this line of thinking any "good" ?

> Can we derive anything about non trivial zeros from above duality?

> Is there any way to manipulate/transform Eq(2) into equation Eq(1)

(Also if anything wrong with the analysis please correct me I'm just a student )

I'm highly doubtful about all this but some people in my local maths community think this is original , but i know original doesn't mean fruitful so asking here.

Can we treat the above duality with operator theory such that the zeros of Zeta comes as eigenvalues of some operator (after suitable scaling and transformation of the equation)?

Comment: "First of all , I myself is not so sure what I'm asking here but please bear with me ." I am also not so sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @davidlowryduda sorry if the questions are not clear enough! I'm trying to build a relation between Zeta zeroes and sum of trigonometric prime sieving machinary mentioned above. Again , if anyone ( with expertise in similar field )  could further give insights about if this line of work is 'good '(in the sense workable for deriving some of the properties of Zeta zeros) is well appreciated.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Also deleted the post from MSE

Comment: Do you see any way to estimate those integrals?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm working on it sir , for F(x) integrals are easy i.e. sub integrals in Stieltjes Integral but for integrals of f(x) in Abel Plana seems extremely hard to deal with (very very very highly oscillatory)

Comment: I don't see it a good idea to put $\Gamma$ inside some trig functions as it turns out that you will need to estimate terms like $\exp\Gamma$ in the complex plane.

Comment: Please please please explain downvotes , if anything is wrong will save my time

Comment: Now up to version 17 of this question.

Comment: Considering the response to @TravorLZH comment, keeping integrals explicit ( no estimates) can we establish exact link between zeta zeroes and the integrals i.e. keeping everything explicit, Also, we can attach 'suitable' weight to sin² function ( suitable in the sense the combined function satisfies growth condition required for Poisson summation/ Abel Plana) and then applying Poisson/ Abel -Plana we can obtain explicit constants ( very very small , in terms of Abel Plana integrals) for ( class of)  convergent sum of  function of primes( equivalently sum of function of Zeta zeros)